# How to distinguish xml from html

Tags: c#, html, xml

I have many files some of which are HTML and other are XML. How can I, provided with a path to a file,  reliably say that, it is XML and not HTML or vice-verse. Desirably using enumeration build-in c# language and not by writing Path.GetExtension(filePath).Equals(".xml")

Comment: Do these files have proper DOCTYPE declarations?

Comment: What do you mean by enumeration build?  How do you handle files that are both or neither?

Comment: Those file have proper DOCTYPE declarations.
@FionaT Nope.

Comment: @Fiona T: XHTML is XML. Well, at least valid XHTML is anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock - question was how OP wanted to 'categorize' xhtml files.   One could simply parse the file, catch the exception and assume it's not xml (and therefore is html) if it doesn't parse.

Comment: @FionaT Don't you find that as an overkill?

Comment: I agree with Fiona. Waiting for the XML parser to fail will be quicker and more reliable than writing your own complex logic to make what would be, at best, a guess.